# JS: Make new array form duplicate values

Tags: javascript

Let's take two arrays for example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Now there is duplicates as we see 4 and 5. How to make new array from them instead of getting rid of them. What is the easiest solution?
So new array should be like:

```
newArray = [4, 5]
```

Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: Did you try any code?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Array.filter() and Array.includes()

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let b = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8];


let arr = a.filter(function(x){
    return b.includes(x);
})

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: he/she has not included his attempt in the question